# javascript - How to reverse bitwise shift?

Tags: javascript

This is my Function. In this function there is two parameter value and how many bits shift.

```
function test(Value, ShiftBits) {
 return (Value << ShiftBits) | (Value >>> (32 - ShiftBits));
};
```

Now i want to make reverse of this function. In this test() function if i put

```
test(105748,7);
```

it returns 13535744;

Now i need to make a function like, if i put

```
rev_test(13535744,7);
```

it returns 105748;

Any help Appreciated.

Comment: Why did you put Python in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not reverse the logic? I *spelled it out* below:

```
Number.prototype.zeroFillBin = function() {
    var s = this.toString(2);
    while (s.length < 32) s = '0' + s;
    return s;
}

function test(val, bits) {
    return (val << bits) | (val >>> (32 - bits));
};

function rev_test(val, bits) {
    return (val >>> bits) | (val << (32 - bits));
};


x = 105748;
y = test(x, 7); // return 13535744
console.log(x + '   = ' + x.zeroFillBin())
console.log(y + ' = ' + y.zeroFillBin() + '\n');

x = 13535744;
y = rev_test(x, 7); // return 105748
console.log(x + ' = ' + x.zeroFillBin())
console.log(y + '   = ' + y.zeroFillBin() + '\n');
```

Results:

```
105748   = 00000000000000011001110100010100
13535744 = 00000000110011101000101000000000

13535744 = 00000000110011101000101000000000
105748   = 00000000000000011001110100010100
```

Comment: NP. [Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more on bit-wise operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
105748 << 1 // 13535744
13535744 >> 1 // 105748
```

Comment: How about if you shift, and add a number. Add recover the added number.